# Express.js Routes Hang on everything but the homepage

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building an app and learning the MEAN stack. I successfully [followed a tutorial on thinkster](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/) last night and was able to get everything working as expected. Now, however, while trying to do this myself, I'm running into issues. The homepage of my app "burbank" loads fine, but the 3 routes I've created just hang. No errors, nothing in terminal, just try forever to load.

`localhost:3000` loads fine

`localhost:3000/contacts` hangs

### index.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Contact = mongoose.model('Contact');
var Event = mongoose.model('Event');
var Vehicle = mongoose.model('Vehicle');

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/contacts', function(req, res, next) {
  Contact.find(function(err, contacts){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(contacts);
  });
});

router.get('/events', function(req, res, next) {
  Event.find(function(err, events){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(events);
  });
});

router.get('/vehicles', function(req, res, next) {
  Vehicle.find(function(err, vehicles){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(vehicles);
  });
});
```

### App.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect = ('mongodb://localhost/burbank');
require('./models/Contacts');
require('./models/Events');
require('./models/Vehicles');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
```

I originally thought this had to do something with the order that I was placing  my requires and variables in app.js, but I don't think that's the case. At any rate, help is much appreciated. I'm *slowly* grasping all these concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes all it takes is a weekend away, a hike at the Grand Canyon and 16 hours in the car to find a syntax error.

`connect.mongoose = ('mongodb://localhost/burbank');`

#### DOES NOT EQUAL

`connect.mongoose('mongodb://localhost/burbank');`

---

To those of you who assisted me, thank you very much. Pardon me while I hang my head in shame.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if the routing works without the mongoose layer using: `res.send("example");`

When using the .find function in mongoose I believe that you have to pass an empty object as the first parameter (if you want to return the entire collection).

Try changing this:

```
Contact.find(function(err, contacts){
```

To this:

```
Contact.find({}, function(err, contacts){
```

Repeat that for all of your find queries.

Comment: It works without the mongoose layer. However changing to what you suggested produces the same results. I'm gonna keep at this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to Mongoose docs, the first parameter for find is a dictionary with the filter you want to apply to documents:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Try something like this:

```
Contact.find().exec(function(err, contacts) { ...
```